# Literature on skill transfer

Tags: reference-request, education-research, reference-books

Motivated by [this other question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/5913/research-on-how-mathematics-skills-transfer-to-other-areas) I'm interested in getting to know the literature on mathematics skills transfer within itself.

All I know is what I've read in David Perkins's book "Knowledge as Design", in which he touches on low road transfer and high road transfer but does not elaborate further and the book is not centered on mathematics.

What are good books dealing with the subject?

Comment: How about [**this**](http://reasoninglab.psych.ucla.edu/KH%20pdfs/Bassok_Holyoak%5B1%5D.1989.pdf) paper on transfer between mathematics and physics? Citation: Bassok, M., & Holyoak, K. J. (1989). Interdomain transfer between isomorphic topics in algebra and physics. *Journal of Experimental Psychology: Learning, Memory, and Cognition, 15* (1), 153.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Definitely counts. Thank you.